# Can i use two AC sources to power one load?

Tags: electrical, power

I have a 1.5 KW Solar array with a 48V  battery storage of 8KW, I am planning on using a 1KVA generator to back up the solar power system in case the solar system cant power the load on its own(both providing power to load at the same time, with priority to solar power system), i can't use an inverter to do this aswell.

Comment: Why can't you use an inverter?

Comment: t i am building this project as a prototype of a grid tied system for my university, but i do not have the authority to use the gird, therefore i am using a generator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on your inverter. Many of the high quality inverters that have an AC input have a mode just for that. When the generator is running, they will meter how much power is being used and if it exceeds the internal (adjustable) set point power level of the generator, it will "support" the generator. i.e. it will produce just enough power to keep the generator loaded to the set point that you program. When large loads need to be run, the inverter augments (supports) the AC source, adding inverter and battery power to ensure that the loads receive the power they demand.

Outback power calls this mode "support mode," Schneider (previously known as Trace, or Xantrex) calls this mode "Generator Support," Magnum Energy calls it "Load Support."

Note from Outback power support-

> IMPORTANT: 
>   If the AC loads exceed the amperage limit setting, the inverter will draw energy from the 
>   batteries. If the loads are sustained, the batteries may discharge to the point of Low 
>   Battery Cut-Out and the inverter may shut down with a Low Battery error.  To prevent the loss of backup power, load use should be planned accordingly.

The only thing that I see that could be a problem is that you specified that (if I understand you correctly) you wanted it to primarily draw off of the solar, and supplement with the generator. The inverters however are designed to primarily pull off the generator and supplement with the solar/battery power. This is so that you don't drain your batteries too much. Generators are actually much more energy efficient (more power per fuel consumption) when they are loaded down (as opposed to running near idle) so most people will advise to primarily use the generator power while it is running so that your batteries will be closer to full when you turn the generator off. But I guess if you wanted to use more of your battery, you could set the "max generator power" lower so that the inverter offsets more of the power.

**Edit based on comments below:** Here is a brief illustration to show a way you can do this. [image: Illustration]
**MAKE SURE** to have a large enough load. 3kW should be enough but too much is better than too little. Program the inverter into grid interactive mode (I'm not sure what that's called for schneider). Just program it the way the manual says to in order to sell power back into the grid. It won't successfully push any power back into the grid (or generator) because your resistive load will fully consume it. The only hurdle that might arise is finding a high amperage 220 outlet to plug it into for your demonstration. I don't think this method would work with a 1kW generator... just too small to support the load.

P.s. This sounds like a pretty expensive school project but it should work and when you are finished with it you can use all the parts for something useful (except maybe the resistive load).

Comment: Thank you for your response, i am actually using a Schneider XW6048 inverter, but i do not want to combine the two sources using the inverter, because as you mentioned, the inverters are designed to primarily pull off the generator, while i want it to primarily pull from the PV system.

I want to design my own system where i can achieve this, it might not make scene when it comes to efficiency, but i am building this project as a prototype of a grid tied system for my university, but i do not have the authority to use the gird, therefore i am using a generator.

Comment: Well that's interesting... as long as you made sure to have a load that was greater than the solar, you could put the inverter into grid interactive mode where the inverter is trying to "sell back" to the generator but as long as all of that power is being consumed by the load it should work fine. Your problem there would be that your generator is so small that when your solar decreases,  your load could overload the generator. Also if your load were not large enough, it could be harmful to the generator to have power pushed back to it. BTW, just curious, what kind of class are you teaching?

Comment: I am actually a student, this is my graduation project, i need to design implement and test a grid tied renewable energy system, the project have been nothing but a hassle, every time i think of a solution it turns out to be a failure, or too complex for me to accomplish, almost feels like i need to build my own custom inverter at this point

Comment: Check out my latest edit... maybe it will help

Comment: BTW, just a quick thought; if you did have it primarily use the generator, and have it suppliment with the solar, would anybody really notice?